# Why is my recursive function updating a list (calculating fibonacci of n)

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, memoization

I'm trying to learn about dynamic programming.  I've gone through an example of how to find the Fibonacci number of an input`n`, while caching the result of each "new" call as I go.

I understand the order in which the function recursively calls: fib(5) -> fib(4) -> fib(3) -> fib(2) -> fib(1) -> fib(0) -> fib(1) -> fib(2) "Cache found" -> fib(3) "Cache found" for n = 5

I'm struggling to understand how the final fib(2) and fib(3) calls have access to the updated cache, as each call only returns an integer, not the list, and I don't think I have the list declared as a global variable.

I originally expected the list to behave like the integer x in my code, so would welcome explanations for how the values have been passed back up.

Code:

```
def fib(n, cache, x):
    print(n, cache)
    print("x: ", x)
    x += 1
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n

    if cache[n] == 0:
        cache[n] = fib(n-1, cache, x) + fib(n-2, cache, x)
    else:
        print("Cache called on", n)

    return cache[n]


def main():
    n = 5
    x = 0
    cache = [0 for _ in range(n+1)]
    print(fib(n, cache, x))
    print(cache)
    print("x: ", x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
5 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x:  0
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x:  1
3 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x:  2
2 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x:  3
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x:  4
0 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x:  4
1 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
x:  3
2 [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
x:  2
Cache called on 2
3 [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
x:  1
Cache called on 3
5
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
x:  0
```

Comment: This sounds like a good time to read about how [Python variables and objects work](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: You are passing the list as an argument all along, so it is wrong to say that function do not have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python function arguments are "passed-by-object" (or pass-by-object-reference). It means that if you pass the list (a mutable object) to a function then elements of the list can be modified. But if you will assign the list by a new list then the list will not change in the caller's scope.

```
def list_scope(l):
    print(l, "id: ", id(l))
    l = [3, 4,5]
    print(l, "id: ", id(l))

def main():
    l = [1, 2, 3]
    print("id: ", id(l))
    list_scope(l)
    print("id: ", id(l))

main()
```

Output:

```
id: 4510275784
[1, 2, 3] id:  4510275784
[3, 4, 5] id:  4509275592
id: 4510275784
```

The id for `l` in `list_scope` before assigning list `[3, 4, 5]` is same as the id in `main`. It changes once `[3, 4, 5]` is assigned, but remain same in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You passed the original of `cache`, rather than a copy (newly-built object).  Thus, each instance of `fib` is working with the *same* object.  An update in one instance is immediately available to the others.  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).